# Node.js and npm installed. Command: install -g zombie, giving issues

Tags: node.js, npm, centos6, mink, zombie.js

When trying to install Zombie JS (command: install -g zombie), I getting many errors. The npm-debug output file is copied below.
I have confirmed that npm and node is installed,

npm -v outputs : `2.7.4`

and

node -v outputs: `v0.13.0-pre`

```
install: missing file operand
Try `install --help' for more information.
/usr/src/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules$ npm install -g zombie
npm WARN engine request@2.54.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine tough-cookie@0.12.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.12"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine iconv-lite@0.4.7: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine eventsource@0.1.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine options@0.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine hawk@2.3.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine http-signature@0.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.8"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine mime-types@2.0.10: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine form-data@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine combined-stream@0.0.7: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine har-validator@1.6.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine delayed-stream@0.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine mime-db@1.8.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine assert-plus@0.1.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.8"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine ctype@0.5.3: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine asn1@0.1.11: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.9"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine chalk@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine commander@2.7.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6.x"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine escodegen@1.6.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine acorn@0.11.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlhttprequest@1.7.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine contextify@0.1.13: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})

> utf-8-validate@1.0.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:66:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:152:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:95:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:744:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:112:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1017:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1089:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32.60xls-domU
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN engine acorn@1.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.4.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine has-ansi@1.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine ansi-styles@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine strip-ansi@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine supports-color@1.3.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine escape-string-regexp@1.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN engine ansi-regex@1.1.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.13.0-pre","npm":"2.7.4"})
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
```

...

update:
I have fixed this by following the advice from @E_net4 and changing the:

node to `v0.12.2` 

and 

npm is `2.7.4`, 

but now when I try installing zombie I get the following error:

```
npm warn unmet dependency which is version 1.0.2
```

Comment: The issue is related to using a "pre" version of node. Can't you avoid installing a stable version?

Comment: If you have a different issue, you should either edit your question or create a new one.